# Query across multiple columns within one sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am currently working to build a query from a Google sheet that will allow me to grab data from two different ranges of cells, my example is below:

```
=query('Form Responses'!A2:F,G2:G "Select * Where F='Yes'")
```

This does not work...

I want to grab data from `A2:F` AND `G2:G` within the same sheet, Form Responses.... how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Similar question at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/111288/query-multiple-ranges-with-results-in-row

Comment: "Doesn't Work" is not a valid problem description. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Generally there is an error of some kind, or improper output, etc. Describe that, describe how you've tried to change, and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do it like this:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses'!A2:K, "select A,B,C,D,E,K,G where F='Yes'")
```

Comment: i added comments as to what i need shown in each sheet